# pycURL; Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, proxy, pycurl

I'm using pycURL to make a few requests to a https site through a http proxy.

Here's my code:

```
import pycurl
buf = cStringIO.StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, url) # 'url' is the base url of the form https://www.target.com
c.setopt(c.PROXY, proxy) # 'proxy' has the form 1.2.3.4:8080
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
c.perform()
```

I've tried this code with different proxies. I get either `Proxy CONNECT aborted` or `Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT`.

Is there something I'm missing? Should I be using https proxies instead? I've looked around and can't seem to find any help or documentation on pycURL's usage.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: sudo apt-get -qy install wireshark, you'll be able to see what wrong with the HTTP, perhaps curl -L also.  
interesting bug btw, I can't see to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem similar to yours, and my error log is:
**fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/nhn/raphael.git/': Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT**
so i use these commond to resolve my problem,
first view your git profile

> git config --global --edit
>   then to delete 
>   config [remote "origin"]
>           proxy = https://github.com/facette/facette.git

Comment: Doesn't seem applicable.